# Cardinality of any set $(a,\infty)\subset\Bbb R$ equal to cardinality of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the cardinality of any open interval ($a, \infty$) where $ a \in \mathbb R$ is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ itself. I know that I need to figure out a bijective function between the two sets to prove their cardinality is the same; I also saw a similar method which used the function $e^x$ as a bijection to the interval ($0, \infty$), but I can't seem to come up with a way to extend that (if it's even possible) to all open real intervals, or any other function that might work.

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: You can attack this with a simple precalc trick:  take any bijective function $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$.  Then the function $x\mapsto f(x)+a$ will be a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(a,\infty)$---this is just a vertical translation of the graph.  If you want intervals of the form $(-\infty,a)$, consider $x\mapsto-f(x)+a$ (this amounts to a vertical reflection of the graph followed by a vertical translation).  by the time to are looking for such bijections, you should have access to high powered tools, but you shouldn't forget the simple ones (just make sure you know why they work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ x \mapsto e ^ { x } + { a } $$